# How big is the smallest warp capable ship in the 40K universe?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In the Horus Heresy short story "Ghosts Speak Not" the lead character Amendera Kendel is given a ship for her mission, it is stated this is one of the smallest warp capable vessels in the Imperium. While it isn't fully described it sounds like it might be about the size of the Serenity from Firefly. It is described as having a cargo hold large enough for 2 land speeders to fit in, several crew quarters, a navigator Room and a cockpit.

Has it ever been stated in the 40K background anywhere (post or pre heresy) how big a vessel needs to be to achieve warp travel safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as general line ships go, the [Viper-Class Scout Sloop](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Viper-class_Scout_Sloop) seems to be one of the smallest warp-capable classes.

[image: Viper-Class Scout Sloop]

> The Viper is the smallest Warp-capable vessel used by the Battlefleet Calixis. The Viper is a fast scout ship, with immensely powerful realspace plasma engines. It is used for short-term spy missions aimed at specific hostile regions [...]

They are listed on the wiki as being 0.95km in length.

It's worth noting that the 40k Wiki lists it as "the smallest Warp-capable vessel used by the Battlefleet Calixis", bespoke ships could theoretically be in use elsewhere by organizations like the Inquisition.

Comment: Great thanks I imagine for artistic licence the ship in "Ghosts speak not" is a bespoke ship as I can't see something nearly  1km in length being to small for legio Astartes to stand upright in the corridors of :)

Comment: I read a novel recently that involved a small, custom-built, warp-capable cutter, but unfortunately I can't remember what the book was. I feel that the ship was either Inquisition, Custodes/Sisters of SIlence (in which case the book may have been _Watchers of the Throne_), or Alpha Legion.

Comment: In the Ian Watson Inquisition wars, there is the warp capable ship 'Tormentum Malorum' which is a small atmosphere capable ship that operated with a crew of 3 http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Jaq_Draco

Comment: @mgh42 interesting. Have you read those books? Do you recall them mentioning it's length? It definitely sounds like it's smaller.

Comment: @mgh42 It's also worth noting that the Inquisition Wars are not really considered canon anymore.

Comment: I read them years ago, they were the first 40k books I ever read.  I seem to remember the ship landing on landing pads in various cities, I will have to see if I still have the book to check